# SQL - Dividing two values

Tags: sql

In SQL, I have a data set of transactions. I am able to get the sum of sales for person A, and the total sales using two separate aggregate functions (see below).

How do I get the percentage of Sales_Person_A / Total_Sales?

**Total Sales**

```
SELECT SUM(sales) AS total_sales
FROM table;
```

**Person A's sales**

```
SELECT SUM(sales) AS Sales_Person_A
FROM table
WHERE salesperson = salespersonA;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subquery` for `totalSales`

```
SELECT (SUM(sales)/(SELECT SUM(sales) AS total_sales
FROM table)) * 100 + '%' as Sales_Person_A_Percentage 
FROM table
WHERE salesperson = salespersonA;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN salesperson = @salespersonA THEN sales END) * 1.0 / SUM(sales)
FROM table;
```

If you want it for all sales people, use aggregation and window functions:

```
select salesperson, sum(sales),
       sum(sales) * 1.0 / sum(sum(sales)) over ()
from table
group by salesperson;
```